# How to bypass router for certain URLs with Vue Router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm using Vue Router with Vue 3 in a web application I'm working on, and have a 'catch all' route defined as the last route:

```
{
    path: "/:catchAll(.*)*",
    component: () => import("pages/Error404.vue")
  },
```

This is picking up *everything*, though, including calls to the /api/ back end (although not via Ajax), and even things like '/test.csv', which is a link to a CSV file in the root directory.
How can I bypass the router for certain URLs, allowing them to be treated as regular requests?
Incidentally, I don't know whether this is relevant, but the application in question is a PWA built using Quasar. When I make the call to e.g '/test.csv', I see a request for 'service-worker.js' with a 304 response code in my nginx access log, confirming that the request is being handled by the router rather than nginx.

Comment: You need to handle that on the server

Comment: How would I handle that on the server? I already have `location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }`. And as I mentioned, no request for the URL is even showing up in the nginx access.log.

Comment: Be careful with your links. Vue router has special links that don't make a network request. Use them only when you actually don't want a network request. If you want to link to a external site or a page not served via vue link to it directly

Comment: Could you please just let me know what I need to do to avoid the router intervening? As I said, something like /api/whatever (which should be a network request) is getting picked up by the router and returning the 404 page.

Comment: This is specific to Quasar and your setup and needs to be accented in the question. Generally Vue is clueless about static files. "When I make the call to e.g '/test.csv'" - how exactly? "confirming that the request is being handled by the router rather than nginx" - it doesn't confirm that, you're on the wrong way. That it's in nginx log means that this went wrong on server side or service worker (which doesn't equal to Vue router)